# Self hosting WCF inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, self-hosting

Thanks to Kent Boogart's answer everything is right now. Thank you very much for all answers!

---

Hello,

I need to self host a WCF service inside WPF gui. I'm using ServiceHost.

But I still can't solve the problem.

First I host a service:

```
ServiceHost host;
Service.ISORClient service = new Service.SORClient();
//The next are in window constructor
host = new ServiceHost(service);
host.Open();
```

And i want to refresh data when I press button, so:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = service.GetPatients();
```

It works, but only once. If I try to refresh it more than one time, it just doesn't work.

Here's my WCF service declaration:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class SORClient : ISORClient
    ... and all the methods come here...
```

Weird thing is, that when I connect from a client app. I can get all the data, and everything is correct. I just can't get the data into GUI (well, I can get it only one time).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: try separating the concerns. I don't think WPF has anything to do with it, but....  perhaps starting with this simple console framework will help. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx

Comment: Issues aside I am wondering why you would want to host WCF in a client application? You're effectively building a fat client so why have the overhead of hosting the application business logic in a service?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not work? Does it throw exception, return no data or return same data? Can you add breakpoint to `GetPatients()` method and make sure its getting a hit when called from `WPF` client?

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside questions of design, I suspect you've been bitten by [the Equals() override issue](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/beware-datacontext-and-equals-overrides/).

Try this to prove it:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = service.GetPatients();
```

Comment: The original blog post you linked to has gone, so I've fixed it for you. I know this is an old answer, but can you publish some of your post here to explain the problem, as blind links to outside resources with no explanation or context are discouraged?